# Streaming to YouTube using FFmpeg Problems

Tags: windows, youtube, ffmpeg, streaming

I am trying to stream to a live event I have created inside of YouTube. I am trying to stream a already created video. The command I am using is noted below.

The problem I have is that YouTube is showing the Streaming status as good (picture attached) and it seems to be receiving the data. But there is no sound and no picture in the live event. I'm not sure what the issue could be.

```
ffmpeg -re -y -i input.mp4 -vcodec libx264 -b:v 600k -r 25 -s 640x360 -filter:v yadif -ab 64k -ac 1 -ar 44100 -f flv "rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/KEY"
```

Image showing YouTube streaming status:

[image: Image showing youtube streaming status]

Console output:

```
ffmpeg version N-60321-g4d7d9a5 Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Feb  2 2014 22:01:03 with gcc 4.8.2 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-av
isynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enab
le-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libcaca --enable-libfreetyp
e --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --ena
ble-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-l
ibopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libsp
eex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-aa
cenc --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavp
ack --enable-libx264 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-zlib
  libavutil      52. 63.100 / 52. 63.100
  libavcodec     55. 49.101 / 55. 49.101
  libavformat    55. 29.101 / 55. 29.101
  libavdevice    55.  7.100 / 55.  7.100
  libavfilter     4.  1.102 /  4.  1.102
  libswscale      2.  5.101 /  2.  5.101
  libswresample   0. 17.104 /  0. 17.104
  libpostproc    52.  3.100 / 52.  3.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'input.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: isommp42
    creation_time   : 2013-10-24 05:44:23
  Duration: 00:41:52.93, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 187 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yu
v420p, 480x360, 89 kb/s, 15 fps, 15 tbr, 30 tbn, 30 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 96
 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2013-10-24 05:44:39
      handler_name    : IsoMedia File Produced by Google, 5-11-2011
[libx264 @ 040fdc40] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX AVX2
 FMA3 LZCNT BMI2
[libx264 @ 040fdc40] profile High, level 3.0
[libx264 @ 040fdc40] 264 - core 142 r2389 956c8d8 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Cop
yleft 2003-2014 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deb
lock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 m
e_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chro
ma_qp_offset=-2 threads=12 lookahead_threads=2 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1
interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1
 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=75 keyint_min=38 scenec
ut=0 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=abr mbtree=1 bitrate=1200 ratetol=1.0 qc
omp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, flv, to 'rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/keyname':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: isommp42
    encoder         : Lavf55.29.101
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (libx264) ([7][0][0][0] / 0x0007), yuv420p, 85
4x480, q=-1--1, 1200 kb/s, 1k tbn, 25 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: mp3 (libmp3lame) ([2][0][0][0] / 0x0002), 44100 Hz,
 mono, fltp, 64 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2013-10-24 05:44:39
      handler_name    : IsoMedia File Produced by Google, 5-11-2011
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 -> libx264)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (aac -> libmp3lame)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame=    1 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.39 bitrate=   9.2kbits/s
...
frame=  463 fps=7.8 q=0.0 size=    1534kB time=00:00:31.66 bitrate= 396.8kbits/s
[flv @ 040fd6e0] Failed to update header with correct duration.
[flv @ 040fd6e0] Failed to update header with correct filesize.
frame=  463 fps=6.8 q=-1.0 Lsize=    2055kB time=00:00:31.79 bitrate= 529.6kbits
/s
video:1778kB audio:249kB subtitle:0 data:0 global headers:0kB muxing overhead 1.
405947%
[libx264 @ 040fdc40] frame I:7     Avg QP: 2.24  size: 44703
[libx264 @ 040fdc40] frame P:153   Avg QP: 0.65  size:  8418
[libx264 @ 040fdc40] frame B:303   Avg QP: 5.74  size:   724
[libx264 @ 040fdc40] consecutive B-frames: 11.9%  2.6%  0.0% 85.5%
[libx264 @ 040fdc40] mb I  I16..4: 66.0% 12.4% 21.6%
[libx264 @ 040fdc40] mb P  I16..4:  4.7%  0.8%  1.5%  P16..4:  6.6%  1.1%  1.1%
 0.0%  0.0%    skip:84.2%
[libx264 @ 040fdc40] mb B  I16..4:  0.2%  0.0%  0.1%  B16..8:  3.0%  0.2%  0.1%
 direct: 0.6%  skip:95.8%  L0:47.7% L1:49.2% BI: 3.0%
[libx264 @ 040fdc40] final ratefactor: -9.42
[libx264 @ 040fdc40] 8x8 transform intra:11.8% inter:35.4%
[libx264 @ 040fdc40] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 33.7% 11.2% 11.1% inter: 2.6% 1.6%
 1.6%
[libx264 @ 040fdc40] i16 v,h,dc,p: 13% 86%  0%  0%
[libx264 @ 040fdc40] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu:  9% 74% 11%  0%  1%  1%  1%
 1%  2%
[libx264 @ 040fdc40] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 17% 61%  6%  1%  3%  2%  4%
 2%  4%
[libx264 @ 040fdc40] i8c dc,h,v,p: 88% 10%  2%  0%
[libx264 @ 040fdc40] Weighted P-Frames: Y:0.0% UV:0.0%
[libx264 @ 040fdc40] ref P L0: 81.7%  9.4%  8.0%  0.9%
[libx264 @ 040fdc40] ref B L0: 78.9% 20.9%  0.2%
[libx264 @ 040fdc40] ref B L1: 99.1%  0.9%
[libx264 @ 040fdc40] kb/s:471.59
Received signal 2: terminating.
```

Edit -

I have now tested the following codes but I still dotn get any picture or sound.. but the health status in youtube still shows good

I ran this command first

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vcodec libx264 -preset medium -maxrate 3000k -bufsize 6000k -vf "scale=1280:-1,format=yuv420p" -g 50 -acodec libmp3lame -b:a 128k -ac 2 -ar 44100 file.flv
```

and then I ran this

```
ffmpeg -re -i file.flv -codec copy -f flv rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/<KEY>
```

I still didnt get any picture

I also tried the full command in 1

```
ffmpeg -re -i input.mp4 -vcodec libx264 -preset veryfast -maxrate 3000k -bufsize 6000k -pix_fmt yuv420p -g 50 -c:a aac -b:a 160k -ac 2 -ar 44100 -f flv rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/<key>
```

still no joy

Comment: You need to show the complete output from your command. Don't forget to obfuscate the key. Also, consider enabling VBV by adding `-bufsize` and `-maxrate` (and `-g`) as shown in [FFmpeg Wiki: Streaming to YouTube](http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/EncodingForStreamingSites).

Comment: Thanks.. Here is the full output 

ffmpeg -re -y -i input.mp4 -vcodec libx264 -x264opts keyint=75:min-keyint=75:scenecut=-1 -b:v 1200k -r 25 -s 854x480 -filter:v yadif -ab 64k -ac 1 -ar 44100 -f flv "rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/keyhere"

Comment: That's a command, not the complete console output.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard I added a new image to the first post.. didnt know how to add another one here http://i.stack.imgur.com/3vmrQ.png

Comment: That's not the complete output (you may omit most of the `frame=` lines if you prefer). Since the output is text, please copy and paste it instead of making an image of text.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard - the code is too long to add

Comment: @LordNeckbeard - I have added the output to a google document here https://docs.google.com/document/d/153_iIrqyPmLyNUkHbnZNWa7iDe1eVpdwZutel1yNv2w/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: It appears you are not encoding at real time. Also, what upload rate do you get at speedtest.net?

Comment: Thanks so much.. My upload speed is 3mbps but I will be using this from places with a lower upload speed.. 

I looked at the details on http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/EncodingForStreamingSites but I just cant seem to get past this.. I even looked at https://sonnati.wordpress.com/2011/08/30/ffmpeg-%E2%80%93-the-swiss-army-knife-of-internet-streaming-%E2%80%93-part-iv/  but I seem to be stuck

Comment: @LordNeckbeard I have updated the first post to add some more commands I have tested out using the suggestions from ffmpeg but still no picture or sound

Comment: If anyone can help then I would highly appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

pass your file through this code:

ffmpeg -i in -r 24000/1001 -vcodec libx264 -x264opts scenecut=0 -tune zerolatency -pix_fmt nv12 -vprofile baseline -preset ultrafast -crf 28 -i_qfactor 0 -g 25 -lavfi afftdn=nt=w:om=o:tn=enabled -flvflags no_duration_filesize -f flv -y out

or

ffmpeg -i in -r 24000/1001 -vcodec h264_qsv -pix_fmt nv12                                       -vprofile baseline -preset veryfast  -vb 3M -i_qfactor 0 -g 25 -lavfi afftdn=nt=w:om=o:tn=enabled -flvflags no_duration_filesize -f flv -y out

then use:

ffmpeg -re -i out -c copy -f flv  rtmp://live.twitch.tv/app/key

or

ffmpeg -re -i out -c copy -f flv rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/key